# Is there a way to pass &mut self from a method that itself takes &mut self?

Tags: rust, ownership

I've got this struct `State` that contains a `Box<dyn Runmode>`. the runmode should be able to be switched, and when it is switched, the old runmode is unloaded (it deallocates it's resources and resets some state), then the box containing the runmode is reassigned, and the new runmode is loaded. When loading a runmode it must be able to access the `State` struct to modify and/or read some things which are essential to the runmode working properly, and when unloading it must be able to reset that state. Here is my code:

```rust
trait Runmode {
    fn load(&mut self, state: &mut State);
    ...
    fn unload(&mut self, state: &mut State);
}

struct State {
    runmode: Box<dyn Runmode>,
    ...
}

impl State {
    pub fn set_runmode(&mut self, mut new_runmode: Box<dyn Runmode>) {
        self.runmode.unload(self);
        // the line above causes errors

        self.runmode = new_runmode;

        self.runmode.load(self);
        // this line also causes errors
    }
}
```

as you may know, this causes the problem of multiple mutable references to a single object, which is not allowed. But I really don't see another way of solving this. Hell, even this won't compile:

```rust
fn switch_runmode(mut state: State, mut new_runmode: Box<dyn Runmode>) {
    state.runmode.unload(&mut state);

    state.runmode = new_runmode;

    state.runmode.load(&mut state);
}
```

What am I forgetting here? In the second example it also says that I'm borrowing mutable twice, but the only mutable borrows I make there is when I load and unload the runmode, and then there's only one mutable reference, the one that goes into the runmodes method.

Comment: Inside `unload`, `self` and `state.runmode` would become mutable aliases, which would lead to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `load` and `unload` do not modify `state.runmode`, you could split `State` into two parts: `runmode` and `nonrunmode`:

```
struct State {
    runmode: Box<dyn Runmode>,
    nonrunmode: NonRunMode, // contains everything else
}
```

Then, `unload` and `load` could take `&mut NonRunMode` as arguments.

```
trait Runmode {
    fn load(&mut self, state: &mut NonRunMode);
    ...
    fn unload(&mut self, state: &mut NonRunMode);
}
```

This should make it clear to the compiler that only distinct parts of `State` are modified.